# How can I hide buttons on an empty subreport in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, attachment, report

Note: I've been debating on whether this should go into SuperUser or StackOverflow... I figure that SU is better, but please let me know is SO is a better fit for this question.

Alright so I'm kind of pulling my hair out over this. I have a database where I'm tracking questions, issues, change requests and more in regards to a piece of software. An important aspect here is to be able to add attachments (bug reports, screenshots, etc.). I read that generally it's better to create your own attachment handling system in Access because using the native attachment field can negatively impact performance, so I did just that. Plus, I prefer my implentation much more than the native implementation for the most part, so that's a bonus.

I created a report with different buttons to add, copy, and delete files with different buttons including the VBA code to handle everything. I then add the report as a subreport to the report or form in question. Example: Someone wants to ask a question and wants to attach a screenshot and an error log. The main form handles things like question and tags, and the subreport handles the attachments. To the right of every record (attachment) I have two buttons - one to open a dialog to copy the file somewhere locally, and the other to delete the attachment. Everything works fine, with one annoyance that should be minor but is really getting on my nerves: when the subreport is empty, it shows the two buttons in the otherwise empty details area. This is pretty confusing to me because I only have this empty line when the report isn't showing any records. As soon as I add an attachment, the new attachment/record uses that line (it's not as if the empty line is Access presenting a row for entering a new record).

In pictures (in German as I'm doing all of this in German):

When the attachments report has records, it looks like this:

[image: Attachments subreport with attachments]

Translations: Anhänge => Attachments; Dateiart => File type; Dateiname => File name; Datum => Date; Größe => Size; Kopieren nach... => Copy to...; Löschen => Delete; Anhang hinzufügen... => Add attachment

I've also blacked out some info for privacy reasons, but I hope everyone gets the idea.

When the subreport has no records, it looks like this:

[image: Subreport with no records]
I've scoured the web for solutions and I have yet to find anything that worked. I've tried setting the buttons to invisible in the "NoData" event, only to figure out that that event doesn't seem to fire when the form is a subform. I've tried adding code to the "Format" event of the details area, but that doesn't seem to fire either. Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this majorly annoying minor annoyance? Ideally I'd also remove the header lines and change the title as well but getting rid of the buttons would be a great start.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an empty record, so try using the *OnCurrent* event of the subform:

```
Me!DeleteButton.Visible = Not Me.NewRecord
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried that, but for the life of me can't figure out where to find the OnCurrent event in the form (everything is in German). But I've tried a number of different methods (for instance load) and they just don't seem to fire when they're in the subform. Also, It returns an error that it doesn't know "NewRecord". Could it be that NewRecord is only available on a form?

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that this is a report. There is no such event in a report.